# Plot_ly bar plot programmed in R does not show texture/ pattern

Tags: r, plotly, bar-chart, textures, r-plotly

I am struggling with adding texture to my plot_ly bar plot implemented in R.
In the code below I try to use the pattern argument inside the marker according to (my understanding of) this documentation: https://plotly.com/r/reference/bar/#bar-marker-pattern .

```
library(plotly)

bar <- plot_ly(
  y = c("First", 
        "Second", 
        "Third"),
  x = c(25, 
        10, 
        5),
  
  type = "bar",
  marker = list(color =  c("#ADEDC1", 
                           "#FFFFA3", 
                           "#FF9393"),
                # Does not seem to work:
                pattern = list(shape = "/", 
                               bgcolor = "black",
                               fgcolor = "blue"
                               )
                )
  )

bar
```

[image: Bar plot without texture]

Yet, as shown in the provided picture, there is no pattern in the bars, but only plain color as specified in the marker's color argument.
Does anyone have a clue how to add pattern to the bars? I would really appreciate any hint, thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code works fine for me. (Using R plotly 4.10.0)

Comment: Urgh, seems to have been an issue due to the older plotly version I used. Thanks for the hint, now it works for me too!